# Conditionally change field visibility depending a many2many in odoo 11

Tags: many-to-many, odoo

I try to change the visibility of a field depending if a element is selected in a many2many relation, but I cannot determine how to write the condition.

I can do this with a one2many,  but doesn't work with a many2many.

For example I have a multi select field with: X Y and Z values, and I want that an another field become visible if Y is selected.

Do you have an example to provide me ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you share your One2many solution which is not working with Many2many?